# Approximation schemes for P-complete problems?

Tags: reference-request, approximation-algorithms, optimization

What work has been done on approximation schemes for $\mathsf{P}$-complete optimization problems? Would the desired approximation algorithms here be "fully log-space approximation schemes" or "fully $\mathsf{NC}$ approximation schemes", analogous to $\mathsf{FPTAS}$ for $\mathsf{NP}$ optimization problems?

Comment: Why is P-completeness a relevant notion for approximations ? Are you limited to logspace in some way ? and why ?

Comment: You might be interested in this paper:
Till Tantau, Logspace Optimization Problems and Their Approximability Properties, Theory of Computing Systems 41(2), pp. 327-350 (2007), http://www.springerlink.com/content/m52274505l5344g6/

Comment: Try searching NCAS and FNCAS.

Answer (score 5):

This one seems related, although it focuses more on parallel time (NC) rather than the closely related space (L): http://www.springerlink.com/content/8hn2q8lvf3ukbbx0/